# Como uma classe de estilo CSS pode herdar de outra classe?

Tags: css, classes, herança

Tenho uma classe `circulo` com várias propriedades: fonte e forma, etc
e tenho outra classe `circulo1` com a propriedade tamanho e cor.

Tenho de fazer vários círculos de tamanhos de diferentes com a mesma cor e em vários lugares diferentes da página. Porém, não consigo fazer com que a classe circulo receba todas as propriedades da class circulo.

```css
.circulo{
    color:#fff;
    line-height:300px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
      
.circulo1 .circulo{
    background:red;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}
      
.circulo2 .circulo{
    background:blue;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}
      
.circulo3.circulo{
    background:red;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}
      
.circulo4.circulo{
    background:blue;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}
      
.circulo5.circulo{
    background:red;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}
      
.circulo6.circulo{
    background:blue;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}

#bloco1{
    margin-left: 0%;
}  
      
#bloco2{
    margin-left: 20%; 
}
#bloco3{
    margin-left: 40%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="bloco1">
    <div id="1" class="circulo circulo1"> Tidbits1</div> 
    <div id="2" class="circulo circulo2">Tidbits2 </div>
</div>
     
<div id="bloco2">
    <div id="3" class="circulo1"> Tidbits3</div> 
    <div id="4" class="circulo2">Tidbits4 </div>
</div>
     
<div id="bloco3">
    <div id="5" class="circulo1"> Tidbits5</div> 
    <div id="6" class="circulo2">Tidbits6 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o teu HTML? Seria ideal ver isto num jsFiddle para poder perceber melhor. Corrige por favor na pergunta: "com que a classe circulo receba todas as propriedades da class circulo" falta aí um `1` não?

Comment: Tem razão...fica melhor no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexjosesilva/2tfpq8eh/

Comment: Acho que em vez de `.circulo1.circulo` devia ser só `.circulo1` uma vez que o HTML tem `class="circulo circulo1"`. Assim => http://jsfiddle.net/2tfpq8eh/1/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Penso que não está claro para ti como funciona a atribuição de múltiplas classes de CSS a um elemento.

### Quando no teu HTML tens:

```html
 <div id="1" class="circulo circulo1"> Tidbits1</div>
```

Estás a dizer que o elemento vai obter os estilos da classe `circulo` e também da classe `circulo1`.

Como a classe `circulo1` vem em segundo lugar, qualquer propriedade dada na classe `circulo1` vai subscrever os valores das mesmas propriedades que tenham sido dadas na classe `circulo`, com exceção para valores sucedidos por `!important`.

### Quando no teu CSS tens:

```css
.circulo2 .circulo {
  /* propriedades aqui */
}
```

Estás a dizer que as propriedades entre os `{}` vai ser atribuídas aos elementos com a classe `circulo` que se encontra dentro de um elemento com a classe  `circulo2`.

Por outro lado, quando tens:

```css
.circulo3.circulo {
  /* propriedades aqui */
}
```

Estás a dizer que as propriedades entre os `{}` vai ser atribuídas aos elementos que tenham ambas as classes `.circulo3` e `.circulo`.

**Nota:**

O `id` de um elemento não pode começar por números, ver [documentação](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

---

Se pretendes ter uma classe com propriedades base e classes auxiliares para definir propriedades especificas, deverás:

**CSS**

```css
.classeBase {
  /* propriedades aqui */
}

.classEspecifica {
  /* propriedades aqui */
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="meuId1" class="classeBase classEspecifica"></div>
```

Assim estás a dar todas as propriedades definidas na classe `classeBase` a este elemento e também a acrescentar as propriedades definidas na classe `classEspecifica`.

Comment: Existe uma maneira de adicionar atributos a uma classe ja existente? A intenção é adicionar numa classe de um arquivo css externo. Num arquivo local eu adicionei o mesmo nome da classe e inseri os atributos desejados, ela manteve os atributos originais e passou a ter os que adicionei mas não sei se isso é certo.

Answer (score -1):

44
Penso que não está claro para ti como funciona a atribuição de múltiplas classes de CSS a um elemento.
Quando no teu HTML tens:

```
 <div id="1" class="circulo circulo1"> Tidbits1</div>
```

Estás a dizer que o elemento vai obter os estilos da classe circulo e também da classe circulo1.

Como a classe circulo1 vem em segundo lugar, qualquer propriedade dada na classe circulo1 vai subscrever os valores das mesmas propriedades que tenham sido dadas na classe circulo, com exceção para valores sucedidos por !important.
Quando no teu CSS tens:

```
.circulo2 .circulo {
  /* propriedades aqui */
}
```

Estás a dizer que as propriedades entre os {} vai ser atribuídas aos elementos com a classe circulo que se encontra dentro de um elemento com a classe circulo2.

Por outro lado, quando tens:

```
.circulo3.circulo {
  /* propriedades aqui */
}
```

Estás a dizer que as propriedades entre os {} vai ser atribuídas aos elementos que tenham ambas as classes .circulo3 e .circulo.

Nota:

O id de um elemento não pode começar por números, ver documentação (Inglês):

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Se pretendes ter uma classe com propriedades base e classes auxiliares para definir propriedades especificas, deverás:

CSS

```
.classeBase, .ClasseEspecifica {
     background-color: 808080;
     text-align: center;
     height: 50px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-weight:bold;
     font-size: 21px; 
     font-family: Arial;
     font-style: italic;

}

.classEspecifica {
    aqui vai o que precisa mudar

}
```